Why can't I connect to VM from VirtualBox using WSL?
The problem is that when I am trying to connect with ssh to VMs, I am getting "Connection timed out"
So, I did almost everything the same as here. Here is an exact order what I have done:

vagrant init ubuntu/focal64 and then vagrant up . It all was done in PowerShell and the provider for vagrant is VirtualBox

I created a port forwarding port forwarding image

From WSL I entered cat /etc/resolv.conf. Result: wsl image

And then I am trying ssh -p 3322 vagrant@172.17.32.1 and get connection timed out.


What am I doing wrong? I would be really gratefull for any help! Thanks!

Why do you think 172.17.32.1 is the address where port forwarding is happening? I suspect this is the address of your MS-Windows host on the WSL bridge.  Check what address your MS-Windows machine is using to connect to the outside.

Okay guys, I have made it. The problem was that WSL and Windows have a firewall between. Here is where I found about it: https://superuser.com/questions/1449775/windows-wsl-2-cant-ping-host-machine
What else would be useful: https://superuser.com/questions/1714002/wsl2-connect-to-host-without-disabling-the-windows-firewall
So in the end, I added a new inbound rule on windows for that port and everything started to work
